The close vote reason isn't working properly?
The question about Dune part III has been closed and reopened.
It's not whether either reasons are good or bad, it's about what happened after the different actions.
Once the question was reopened, I had the following message:

You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote.

I did not retract a close vote. On the stackexchange network, I'm pretty sure one can't vote to close twice, but it's not something I did either.
So, either the system thinks I wanted to close twice (I wasn't, I was just checking the VTC reasons on the first available question on top of the list), or the message is completely wrong.
Is this behaviour by design, a mistake or a bug?



That bug has actually been reported before on Meta Stack Exchange: When a retraction is not a retraction. Please update close-menu message. It was marked as status-review, which means that SE staff are aware of the issue and are reviewing it.
However, that was way back in February 2022—over two years ago. It's possible that it got lost in the shuffle or deprioritized for some reason.

I think it means "once a vote has been retracted" however that happens. Either by actual retraction or a close vote is (effectively) overridden by a "reopening".
I tested on the same question and I think this is the case. I voted to close originally, voted to re-open after clarification and now I get the same message. Essentially, you only get one close vote ever.
